# Are pictures inside a <details> tag loaded before or after you "open" the details?

Tags: html, bandwidth, html-tag-details

Pretty much as the title says, if I put an image inside a details tag will I save bandwidth for the user, so it won't load until they open it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you save nothing. The image will be loaded as the rest of the page. It will be visible on demand as is defined by the details tag.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the W3C defines any such loading behavior, so this is likely implementation-dependant. That is to say, **no, this won't guarantee that this saves your user any bandwidth, but if you want to collapse the image and hope to save your users as much bandwidth as possible, this is your best pure-HTML bet.**